# Entity Framework - passing different object sets as a parameter in a function

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework

I have the following code:

```
Private Sub setDropdowns()
    Using licensingModel As New licensingEntities
        SetUpDropdowns(licensingModel.tblLookup_Country, "CountryName", "CountryName", country)
        SetUpDropdowns(licensingModel.tblLookup_Country, "CountryName", "CountryName", bizCountry)
        SetUpDropdowns(licensingModel.tblLookup_Salutation, "SSalutation", "SSalutation", salutation)
        SetUpDropdowns(licensingModel.tblLookup_OrgType, "OrgType", "OTAuto", organisationType)
    End Using
End Sub
```

and the sub SetUpDropdowns:

```
Private Sub SetUpDropdowns(ByVal entity As IObjectSet(Of EntityObject), ByVal textColumn As String, ByVal valueColumn As String, ByVal combo As RadComboBox)
    combo.DataSource = entity
    combo.DataBind()
End Sub
```

My problem is that i dont know how to define the parameter type for the sub.  Because they are different types of objectSets being passed each time, I thought `IObjectSet(Of EntityObject)` would work, but it gives me the following error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet`1[licensingModel.tblLookup_Country]' to
>   type
>   'System.Data.Objects.IObjectSet`1[System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityObject]'‌

Would anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: this is the error btw:

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet`1[licensingModel.tblLookup_Country]' to type 'System.Data.Objects.IObjectSet`1[System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityObject]'.

Comment: Welcome to SO, +1 for your first question.

Comment: Have you tried to define generic method?

Comment: i could use a generics alright.  But i thought i could use the other approach i am trying above as i would think it is better?

Answer (score 0):

can you not just use object as your parameter?

Comment: i suppose i could :) just not very nice.  but i might do that thanks!